# issue with isset giving a white page

Tags: php

For the past two hours I've been on Google trying to solve this before coming to ask for help, I was really hoping I would of been able to solve this, but unfortunately I've hit a brick wall.

This is for a menu item in bootstrap, I'm asking PHP, if `$page_title = "Index"` is set, the list item will be highlighted, else it won't be highlighted, but all I'm getting at the moment is a blank page, any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
<li <?php echo isset($page_title == "Index" ? "class='active'" : ""); ?>>
    Index
</li>
```

Edit: I have the following below in my php file, but the page is still blank.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: what is the `$_GET[value]` of your index page

Comment: have you get some errors from php?

Comment: If you want to say *if $page_title = "Index" is set* - then use `$page_title == "Index"` - `isset()` is used to see if a field is set and not if a variable is set to some specific value.

Comment: I have ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); in my file, but it's still a blank page

Comment: It's not syntactically correct. You probably want `<?php echo isset($page_title) && $page_title == "Index" ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>`.

Comment: @Qirel that fixed it, thank you very much! i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I reopened the question. @Qirel should/can post an answer for it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can i ask why you closed it before Qirel answered? just so i can learn from the mistake i made, thank you.

Comment: Usually a blank screen means syntax errors, but this seems to have been an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not entirely correct. The `isset()` function will return a boolean (true/false), and this cannot be compared against the value of the variable, which is a string.

You should first check if the variable is set, then check its value separately, as shown below.

```
<li <?php echo isset($page_title) && $page_title == "Index" ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>>
```

- http://php.net/isset